# How to display a feed using PHP and MySqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, server

I have a table called **users_friends**. Within this table are 4 columns, **user_one**, **user_two**, **status**, and created(Date Created).

If the status is set to "2" then both users are friends. Else, they are in a pending friend request.

I would like to display a feed page by getting posts from my table **posts** where the user_id is equal to the id(current_user), and then all of their friends in the **user_friends** table. What would the mysql statement be? I'm stuck.

This is how I get a user's friends.

```
$conn = conn();
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users_friends WHERE status='2' AND (friend_one='$id' OR friend_two='$id')");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               $fndOne = $row["friend_one"];
               $fndTwo = $row["friend_two"];
               if ($fndOne == $id) {
                    $fndIs = $fndTwo;
               } elseif ($fndTwo == $id) {
                    $fndIs = $fndOne;
               }
               //Just shows it works
               echo "$fndIs<br />";
          }
     }
```

Is there a better way to get the users friends? Because I cant't seem to figure out how to get the users friends and the current user and then display all the posts ordered by post_id DESC.

Comment: friend_one is basically the current user and friend_two is their friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$qry="SELECT user_one,user_two FROM user_friends WHERE (user_one='$id' || user_two='$id') AND status=2"; 
$res=mysqli_query($qry);
while($res_fetch=mysqli_fetch_object($res))
{



$qry_p="SELECT * FROM post WHERE (user_id='$res_fetch->user_one' || user_two='$res_fetch->user_one' || user_id='$res_fetch->user_two' || user_two='$res_fetch->user_two')"
$res_p=mysqli_query($qry_p);
while($res_fecth_p=mysqli_fetch_object($res_p))

{
/* Your Post*/

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use an inner join in your SQL statement and join the users_freinds.user_id = posts.user_id and get the data that way?

or am i misinterpreting what you are asking?